# Inverse the fore- and background color for the current tab in tmux

Tags: tmux

Since I often change the terminal color scheme from dark to bright and vice versa, I do not want to use hard-coded colors, but just inverse the colors. I guess somewhere

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format ...?
```

Comment: _Just_ the current `tmux` pane? If you have split window, you just want to invert te colours in one of the panes?

Comment: I want to change the color of the `window-status-current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set -g window-status-current-attr reverse` in your `~/.tmux.conf` file.

[image: Reversed colors in statusbar]

Comment: I've changed `style` to `attr`. That should be more compatible and should not cause any error messages.